# Playwright: Ensuring parallel tests run in their own rooms

Tags: typescript, jestjs, playwright

I'm testing something like a chat application with Playwright. I'm running tests in parallel and need to make sure that each test doesn't interfere with other tests. Here's my solution so far:

```
const chatRooms = [1, 2, 3]
const chatroomsInUse = new Map<number, boolean>(chatRooms.map(i => ([i, false])))
async function runInUnusedChatroom(test: (chatroom: number) => void) {
    for (let room of chatRooms) {
        const inUse = chatroomsInUse.get(room);
        if (!inUse) {
            chatroomsInUse.set(room, true)
            try {
                await test(room)
                return
            } finally {
                chatroomsInUse.set(room, false)
            }
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Unable to find available chatroom")
}

test("A simple test", async () => {
  await runInUnusedChatroom(room => {
    // This test will run in chatroom 1
  })
})

test("Another test", async () => {
  await runInUnusedChatroom(room => {
    // This test will also run in chatroom 1... but I expect it to run in chatroom 2 when I run in parallel.
  })
})
```

I understand this behaviour is because each test runs in its own worker, so has its own instance of `chatroomsInUse`.

The only other thing I can think of doing is coding an endpoint into my chatroom web server that provides an id of an empty chatroom, a lock of some kind.

Is there a better way to spread my tests across my chatrooms and still run them in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
const chatRooms = [1, 2, 3]

// our chatrooms aren't actually 1,2,3 so we have to index into it
const getChatroom(parallelIndex: number) {
  return chatRooms[parallelIndex]
}

test("A simple test", async ({}, {parallelIndex}) => {
  const chatrooms = getChatroom(parallelIndex)
  // parallelIndex will be 0 here
})

test("Another test", async ({}, {parallelIndex}) => {
  const chatrooms = getChatroom(parallelIndex)
  // parallelIndex will be 1 if tests are run in parallel
})
```

Parallel index is described here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-workerinfo#worker-info-parallel-index

> The index of the worker between 0 and workers - 1. It is guaranteed that workers running at the same time have a different parallelIndex